# StatusStrip's items property in custom user control

Tags: vb.net

I am making a custom **status bar** control and as is easily understood, I have included a `StatusStrip` control. I am trying to create an new `Items` property to this custom control but I am missing something here and I get this error...

```
BC30526 Property 'Items' is 'ReadOnly'.
```

Here is how I am trying to do that...

```
Public Property Status_Items As ToolStripItemCollection
    Get
        Return StatusStrip.Items
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ToolStripItemCollection)
        StatusStrip.Items = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Any ideas?

Comment: StatusStrip.Items.Add() ?

Comment: I get this error: `BC30516 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' accepts this number of arguments.`

Comment: StatusStrip.Items.AddRange(value) ?? Maybe, it's hard to tell without more code.

Comment: No it doesn't work...

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: There is nothing special! It's just a new custom user control and I am trying to add some properties...

Comment: The `ToolStripItemCollection` is readonly so that you cannot do what you are trying to do: replace the entire collection. It is a type with its own methods including Add and Remove so that it can do what it needs to do when the collection is modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Property StatusBar_Items As ToolStripItemCollection
    Get
        Return StatusStrip.Items
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ToolStripItemCollection)
        StatusStrip.Items.AddRange(value)
    End Set
End Property
```

You can't add to a return. Because `.AddRange`doesn't return anything. I think you got your Get and Set mixed up.

Comment: It doesn't give any error in code but when I am testing the control and click on (Collection) it gives me an error message box "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value".

Comment: You must be sending a null reference to the 'StatusBar_Items' property